# How to retrieve list item URl when Approval Status is Pending

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

I am creating a approval workflow, where i collect data from diffrent users in diffrent stages. My workflow logic is as follows:

- When new item is created and if item approval status is pending.
     Collect Data from User 1( As listed in the new item form).

In Collect Data Task i created a column to capture Review status of that job.
                 If the approval status is approved : go to next step.
                **else if approval status is request for more info: send email to user who created the item with the link of the edit form to make changes and send back again.**

At this very step i need to capture the url of current item and block certain fields in editform.aspx page.

I was able to do that using jquery targeting input title of that item and disable it.

But now when User 1 approves his task and the approval workflow moves on to USer 2 where user 2 send back the form for a review i need to block User 1 (people and group Field) but still keep user 2(people and group field) enabled in editform.aspx page of that item.